# How to say "I have sent your words to students" in formal way?

Tags: phrases, email

I'm a teacher and I've asked another teacher about his opinion over a matter and he replied. 
I have told students about his opinion and now I am replying back to him again. I don't know how to say

> I have sent your words to students.

in a very formal and polite way.

Comment: There are several factors to consider first. Pragmatics are at least as important as semantics and syntax. (1) Did you have his permission to pass on the information? (2) Are you peers organisationally? (3) Are you peers in your discipline? . . .

Comment: *Conveyed* -- "I have **conveyed** your words to the students."

Comment: You just used the words "I have told students about his opinion" to explain the situation to us, total strangers. So certainly they are appropriate enough to be used to explain the situation to someone you know.

Comment: I like Kris's "conveyed", but instead of "words", perhaps "your opinion on the matter"; "your words* goes beyond formality into reverence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of these would fit.

- "I have transmitted your opinion to my students."
- "Your view on the subject has been transmitted to my students."
- "I've made your opinion known to my students."

If you want to sound more formal, you could add: "**I've taken the liberty** to transmit ..."

Answer (score 0):

A few factors that I could consider on the type of information/opinion :

If the opinion has overtones of order:

- [instruct, inform](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/instruct?q=instructed)

If the talk was to to clear up, to remove confusion:

- [**enlighten**, educate](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/enlighten)

If the talk was just to fill them in:

- [**apprise**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/apprise), [share](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/communicate)
- etc.